# a word for "to agree without sincerity"

Tags: single-word-requests

As in:

> "There is nothing wrong with learning from the enemy, you see, an attack of this scale is much more efficient with collective organization."
>
> "Indeed," she ____, "if only my people were susceptible to such wisdom."

Context: first speaker is running his mouth off with a lecture about leadership, the second speaker expresses agreement without sincerity in order to flatter the first.

Comment: _Giving lip service (to s.t.)_ is the usual idiom. Though that doesn't constitute a speech act you could use in dialog as above; it's more a comment on the pragmatics of the situation. Note it is not a single word. English has at most a million distinct words, of which no one ever learns more than a fraction, but a million is ***way*** too small a number for every possible concept one can imagine. So usually there isn't a single English word for a concept. I always wonder why people think there is, much less why there should be.

Answer (score 3):

I'm reading this as 'to agree reluctantly'.

The usual choice of quotative verb is **concede**.

> "Indeed," she conceded, "if only my people were susceptible to such
>   wisdom."

From [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concede):

> *concede* [verb] ​
>
> to admit, often unwillingly, that something is true:
>
> [ + (that) ] *The government has conceded (that) the new tax policy
>   has been a disaster.*
>
> [ + speech ] *"Well okay, perhaps I was a little hard on her," he
>   conceded.*

However, **acquiesce** also shows a reluctant agreement, with more emphasis on submissive/obsequious acceptance: {[from M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiesce)}

> *acquiesce* [verb]:
>
> to accept, comply, or submit tacitly or passively — often used with
>   in or to

Though rarer as a quotative verb, it *is* used:

> "Well, that ought to be reason enough," he acquiesced.

{[Kate Chopin - The Awakening](http://www.pbs.org/katechopin/library/awakening/chapter27.html)}

Answer (score 2):

You might consider ***fawned***

"Indeed," she ***fawned***, "if only my people were susceptible to such wisdom."

Defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fawn) as:

> to court favor by a cringing or flattering manner *courtiers fawning on the king*

Comment: Do you have an example where it is used as a quotative verb?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe dissemble:

> [no object]
>   1.Conceal or disguise one's true feelings or beliefs. ‘an honest, sincere person with no need to dissemble’
>
> 1.1 with object, Disguise or conceal (a feeling or intention) 'she smiled, dissembling her true emotion’
>  [Oxford Living
>   Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dissemble)

Your example sentence:

> "Indeed," she dissembled, "if only my people were susceptible to such
>   wisdom."

Answer (score 0):

appease - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/appease 
To swiftly move on from ones rant/issue, in hope of not creating further issue or problem. to tell one what they want to hear to achieve progress/-an end of ones thought---to another.